# How to add graphic file explorer in MobaXterm?

Tags: mobaxterm

When I'm connecting to a ssh server, there is a file explorer in the left side:

(https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/img/moba/features/feature-sftp-browser.png)

But when I use the local terminal, it does not appear. How can I use this in a local terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Moba menus & configurations can be quite confusing and I too struggled to figure this out even after years of using this app, here's what went wrong:

It is most likely you saved previous machine session settings, while accidentally changed the default global SSH settings of your Moba client - let's fix it.

1. Navigate to ***settings*** menu and select ***configure***:

[image]

2. Select the ***SSH*** tab, and make sure to enable ***graphical SSH-browser*** and ***Automatically switch to SSH-browser tab after login***:
   [image]
3. Relaunch your MobaXterm app, and connect to your remote host - the file browser should open automatically upon successful login.